# Clustering of two datasets in different years

Tags: time-series, clustering, unsupervised-learning, similarity

I want to analyze two datasets by running a clustering algorithm on both and comparing the results. The two datasets have the same variables. The only difference is that one dataset is from 2010 and the other is from 2022. Would it make sense to run a clustering algorithm using the same specifications on both datasets for comparison? e.g. If 2010 cluster has 11 optimal clusters while 2022 has 9 optimal clusters, can I deduce that the dataset got less 'fragmented'.

Please advise.